# AWS Lambda function to check whether the site is available

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to create an AWS Lambda function to check whether the site is available. I tried this function.

```
'use strict';

var url = require('url');
var target = 'https://www.google.com'; // Change this one

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  var urlObject = url.parse(target);
  var mod = require(
    urlObject.protocol.substring(0, urlObject.protocol.length - 1)
  );
  console.log('[INFO] - Checking ' + target);
  var req = mod.request(urlObject, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      console.log('[INFO] - Read body chunk');
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      console.log('[INFO] - Response end');
      callback();
    });
  });

  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('[ERROR] - ' + e.message);
    callback(e);
  });
  req.end();
};
```

I tried this in "How it works" section before create the actual function. But when I run this, I get an error "Process exited before completing request"

[image]

My objective is to send an alert if the site is down (using AWS cloud-watch).

Comment: Is your function inside a VPC? If yes, do you have NAT enabled?

Comment: @Shuvojit Nope. Not under a VPC

Comment: does the code work if you run it local? e.g. with `exports.handler({}, {}, console.log)`?

Comment: Have you considered using the Health Check capabilities of Amazon Route 53? It can do this for you, and trigger notifications when a health check fails.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Will that notify if the site is down (eg; 503 - The service is unavailable)

Comment: Yes. It will also trigger an Amazon CloudWatch metric that you can use to trigger alerts, so CloudWatch will both maintain a history and allow you to react. See: [Creating Amazon Route 53 Health Checks and Configuring DNS Failover - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your code terminates because you're invoking `req.end` before any the events are invoked. Under the hood, these APIs use the `EventEmitter` API in NodeJS so it publishes events to the channels that are listening to them, but since all of this happens asynchronously, `req.end` is being invoked before any of these events are fired.

You can greatly simplify your code by using the `request` module. Just pack it with your dependencies.

I have refactored your code a little bit to use [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) as well, so I needed to promifisy the callback. It's a good practice to do so. If you want to send a notification when something goes wrong, just put the code inside the `catch` block.

```
'use strict';

const target = 'https://www.google.com'; // Change this one
const request = require('request')

const handler = async (event) => {

    try {
        const data = await new Promise((res, rej) => {
            request.get(target, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    return rej(err)
                }
                return res(data)
            })
        })
        console.log(data)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        //send notification
    }

};
```